# How do I have Mapbox annotations show up with current location information

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, annotations, mapbox

I was wondering if anyone may know how to make Mapbox annotations be able show the current location information once dropped on a certain spot. Kind of like it does in Apple's maps when you tap on a pin or drop one and it then shows the locations name or address. I have the code for the pin being dropped but after that I don't know how to make it show information on that current location. Thank you for your feedback in advance.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Mapbox

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView: MGLMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func markStuff(_ sender: Any) {

        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]

         let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        mapView.setCenter(center, zoomLevel: 15, animated: true)

        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to **reverse geocode** the coordinate of the annotation. The Mapbox iOS SDK does not offer this capability out of the box, but we do provide a library called [MapboxGeocoder.swift](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift).

Comment: Thank you I have tried that but I don’t know how to import it because when I use the cocoa pods and do it all then open Xcode and type in import MapboxGeocoder it tells me no such module exists...